# Cannot enable GSS-TSIG updates from Active Directory in BIND 9.10

Tags: active-directory, bind, kerberos, gssapi

I’m with a problem trying to enable GSS-TSIG with BIND 9.10.

Before I start describing what I’ve done, I would like to say that I’ve already done this in in another domain without any problems. So I think I’m missing something very specific. If someone would help-me debugging this issue I’ll be very pleased.

Let’s start.

I’m running BIND9 9.10.0P2_5 on FreeBSD 10.0, compiled by myself with the GSSAPI_BASE option enabled. I’ve used this same binary package to deploy it on the other domain that’s working.

Then I’ve enabled GSS-TSIG in my `named.conf` files:

```
options {
    ( … )
    tkey-gssapi-keytab "/etc/krb5.keytab”;
    ( … )
};

zone “local.example.com" {
       type master;
       file "/usr/local/etc/namedb/dynamic/local.example.com";
       notify yes;
       check-names ignore;
       allow-query { clients; };
       allow-transfer { intnameservers; };
#      allow-update {
#              key "iq-rndc-key";
#              domaincontrollers;
#      };
       update-policy {
               grant * subdomain local.iq.ufrj.br. ANY;
       };
};

zone "10.in-addr.arpa" {
       type master;
       file "/usr/local/etc/namedb/dynamic/10.in-addr.arpa";
       notify yes;
       allow-query { clients; };
       allow-transfer { intnameservers; };
#       allow-update { 
#               key "iq-rndc-key"; 
#               domaincontrollers;
#       };
       update-policy {
               grant * subdomain 10.in-addr.arpa. PTR TXT;
       };
};
```

Then I’ve joined the AD domain using Samba4 and Kerberos, in this way:

Created the file `/etc/krb5.conf` with the following content:

```
[libdefaults]
    default_realm = EXAMPLE.COM
    dns_lookup_realm = true
    dns_lookup_kdc = true
    ticket_lifetime = 24h
    renew_lifetime = 7d
    forwardable = yes
```

Installed Samba 4.1 and created the file `/usr/local/etc/smb4.conf` with the following content:

```
[global]
    security = ads
    realm = EXAMPLE.COM
    workgroup = EXAMPLE

    kerberos method = secrets and keytab

    client signing = yes
    client use spnego = yes
    log file = /var/log/samba4/%m.log
```

Asked for a Administrator Kerberos Ticket:

```
$ kinit Administrator
```

Then join the domain and create a keytab

```
$ net ads join createupn=dns/server-hostname.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM -k
$ net ads keytab create -k
```

After all I’ve successfully received a ticket, created a computer account, and a service principal account with success.

The next step was a chown bind to the `/etc/krb5.keytab` so BIND9 can read the keytab successfully.

After all, nothing is working… GSS-TSIG doesn't even give errors in the logs, which is frustrating. I’m trying to debug this with those options in named.conf:

```
logging {

       channel update_log {
               file "/var/log/named/bind-ddns-updates.log";
               severity debug;
               print-category yes;
               print-severity yes;
               print-time yes;
       };

       category update {
               update_log;
       };

       category update-security {
               update_log;
       };
};
```

But I don’t see anything useful in the log file.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Should the update-policy statement be: "grant * ms-subdomain local.iq.ufrj.br. ANY;" if updates are coming from Windows?